# select query in Cursor taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have designed a cursor to run some stats against 6500 inspectors but it is taking too long. There are many other select queries in cursor but they are running okay but the following select is running very very slow. Without cursor select query is running perfectly fine.

**Requirements:**

Number of visits for each inspectors where visits has uploaded document (1 or 2 or 13)

**Tables:**

- `Inspectors: InspectorID`
- `InspectionScope: ScopeID, InspectorID (FK)`
- `Visits: VisitID, VisitDate ScopeID (FK)`
- `VisitsDoc: DocID, DocType, VisitID (FK)`

Cursor code:

```
DECLARE 
        @curInspID int, 
        @DateFrom date, @DateTo date;

SELECT @DateTo = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
       ,@DateFrom = CAST(GETDATE() - 90 AS DATE)


DECLARE  
        @InspectorID int,
        @TotalVisits int;


DECLARE @Report TABLE (
        InspectorID int,
        TotalVisits int)


DECLARE curList CURSOR FOR
    SELECT InspectorID FROM Inspectors ;        


OPEN curList
FETCH NEXT FROM curList INTO @curInspID;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT 
    @curInspID = s.InspectorID    
    ,@TotalVisits = COUNT(distinct v.visitID)
from Visits v 
inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
inner join VisitDocs vd on vd.VisitID = v.VisitID 
where s.InspectorID = @curInspID and vd.DocType IN (1,2,13) 
and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo
group by s.InspectorID 


INSERT INTO @Report VALUES(@curInspID,@TotalVisits);

FETCH NEXT FROM curList INTO @curInspID;
END

CLOSE curList
DEALLOCATE curList

SELECT * FROM @Report
```

Following queries run okay inside the same cursor

```
    ,@TotalVisitsWithReportScore = (select COUNT(v.visitid) from visits v
                        inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
                        where v.ReportStandard not in (0,9) and v.VisitType = 1
                            and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo
                            and s.InspectorID = @curInspID 
                            )

    ,@TotalVisitsWith_ReportScore_RejectionFeedBack = (select COUNT(v.visitid) from visits v
                        inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
                        where v.ReportStandard not in (0,9) and v.VisitType = 1
                            and v.DiscrepancyType IN (2,5,6,7,8)
                            and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo
                            and s.InspectorID = @curInspID 
                    )
```

Comment: I have seen issues before when running a query with cursors. If you cancel it half way through it will keep the open cursors in memory.

Comment: please, clarify - is a single select inside your cursor running slow being compared with the same parameters select but outside cursor, or total of your 6500 iterations of this select are slower than you are expecting?

Comment: @Andy, Select outside cursor take less than 8 sec with same parameters but inside it take more than 1 min. There are many other select queries in this same cursor which are running fine but to make this example shorter i have included the one which is running slow. I have updated my question with few other queries which are running okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a cursor here -- you can use `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT`, joining on the `Inspector` table.

```
INSERT INTO @Report 
SELECT 
    s.InspectorID    
    , COUNT(distinct v.visitID)
from Visits v 
    inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
    inner join VisitDocs vd on vd.VisitID = v.VisitID 
    inner join Inspector i on s.InspectorID = i.InspectorId 
where vd.DocType IN (1,2,13) 
and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom and @DateTo
group by s.InspectorID
```

---

Please note, you may need to use an `OUTER JOIN` with the `Inspector` table if there are results in that table that do not exist in the other tables.  Depends on your data and desired results.

Comment: i have already used INSERT INTO with SELECT but like to know why it is too slow when run inside cursor.

Comment: @user1263981 - Cursors are very slow.  Generally speaking, try to stay away from them.  When using a cursor, you are running select/insert multiple times, 1 for each record in your inspector table.  So if you have 100 records in your inspector table, that's 200 sql calls!  This just runs once.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to speed up a cursor is.... **to get rid of it**!

Here, you **definitely** don't need a cursor - a simple `SELECT` will do - and should be **substantially** faster!

```
DECLARE @Report TABLE (InspectorID int, TotalVisits int)

DECLARE curList CURSOR FOR
    SELECT InspectorID FROM Inspectors ;        


OPEN curList
FETCH NEXT FROM curList INTO @curInspID;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Report (InspectorID, TotalVisits)
   SELECT 
      i.InspectorID,
      COUNT(v.visitID)
   FROM 
      dbo.Inspectors i
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.InspectionScope s ON s.InspectorId = i.InspectorId
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Visits v ON s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.VisitDocs vd ON vd.VisitID = v.VisitID 
   WHERE 
      vd.DocType IN (1, 2, 13) 
      AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
   GROUP BY
      s.InspectorID 

SELECT * FROM @Report
```

Comment: @user1263981: well then you need to start checking your indexing - are all the **foreign key** columns properly indexed? Do you have indices on `vd.DocType` and `v.VisitDate` ??

Answer (score 1):

Cursors is not recommended any more. It is better for you to insert the data into a temporary table and add a primary key to it.

So in your loop you will have a while loop that loops through your table with a WHERE clause on your Id in the temporay table.

That is much much more faster.