# How to implement this logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have designed a script to get the inspector performance score which is based on different factors. Inspector is awarded grades based on their performance score. Script runs over night as a SQL job and updates all the inspectors (over 6500 inspectors) grades.
We are checking last 90 days progress but many inspectors who have done no work in last 90 days are getting full marks. To avoid this situation we have decided to look at last 90 days and if the number of reports is zero go back another 90 days for that inspector.

i.e. If out 6500 inspectors lets say 250 has done no job then script needs to go back another 90 days for those 250 inspectors and see if they have any work.

This could have been implemented in cursors very easily but i can't use cursor as it is taking too long as discussed here [select query in Cursor taking too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767996/select-query-in-cursor-taking-too-long)

What are the other option? Should i write a function which will first check if there is any work been done in last 90 days for one inspector if not then go back another 90 days. But for doing this i would till need cursor?

**ADDED**

I have tried setting dates in temp table as mentioned by @Raj but it is taking too much time. This is a same query which took so long while using cursor. Other stats are running fine and i think something to do with query.

Requirements:

Number of visits for each inspectors where visits has uploaded document (1 or 2 or 13)

Tables:

```
Inspectors: InspectorID
InspectionScope: ScopeID, InspectorID (FK)
Visits: VisitID, VisitDate ScopeID (FK)
VisitsDoc: DocID, DocType, VisitID (FK)



DECLARE 
        @DateFrom90 date, @DateTo date, @DateFrom180 date, @DateFrom date;

SELECT @DateTo = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
       ,@DateFrom90 = CAST(GETDATE() - 90 AS DATE)
        ,@DateFrom180 = CAST(GETDATE() - 180 AS DATE)



DECLARE @Inspectors TABLE (
        InspectorID int,
        InspectorGrade int,
        DateFrom date,
        DateTo date
        );

insert into @inspectors  (
        InspectorID ,
        InspectorGrade,
        DateFrom ,
        DateTo  
        )

select 
tmp.InspectorID  , tmp.InspectorGrade 
,case when tmp.VisitWithReport = 0 then @DateFrom180 else @DateFrom90 end StartDate
,@DateTo EndDate
from
(
    select 
    i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade 
    ,VisitWithReport = (select COUNT(v.visitid) from visits v
    inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
    where v.ReportStandard not in (0,9) and v.VisitType = 1
    and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom90 and @DateTo
    and s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID) 

    from inspectors i
)tmp;

--select * from @Inspectors 

SELECT i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade 
,TotalVisitsWithAtLeastOneReport = (select COUNT(distinct v.visitID) from Visits v 
                            inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
                            inner join VisitDocs vd on vd.VisitID = v.VisitID 
                            where vd.DocType IN (1,2,13) and s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID
                            and v.VisitDate BETWEEN i.DateFrom and i.DateTo

                         )
from @Inspectors  i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the last job/work date first before applying any logic. Like, you can store InspectorID and LastWorkDay in a temp table (assuming LastWorkDay will be available in some table). Then based on LastWorkDay you can decide how many days you have to go back - 90 or 180. This will be another field  (StartDate) in temp table which can be derived based on LastWorkDay column.

Comment: i tried your login of temp table but i am stuck on one select statement which is taking too long. Please check my question, i have added my script there.

Comment: I have checked my sql in query tunning advisor and after creating following non cluster indexes, sql script is now taking only two to three seconds to execute. I will test this more and will see if it is not going to effect other part of the system before implementing in live.

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [DocType_VisitID] ON [dbo].[VisitDocs] 
    (
 [DocType] ASC,
 [VisitID] ASC
    )WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON  [PRIMARY]

Comment: Hope you are able to implement!!