# Query is running very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have designed a sql query to run some stats against 6500 inspectors but it is taking too long. There are many other select queries in sql but they are running okay but the "TotalVisitsWithAtLeastOneReport" select is running very very slow.

Requirements:

- Number of visits for each inspectors where visits has uploaded document (1 or 2 or 13)

Tables:

```
Inspectors: InspectorID
InspectionScope: ScopeID, InspectorID (FK)
Visits: VisitID, VisitDate ScopeID (FK)
VisitsDoc: DocID, DocType, VisitID (FK)
```

SQL:

```
DECLARE 
        @DateFrom90 date, @DateTo date, @DateFrom180 date, @DateFrom date;

SELECT @DateTo      = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
      ,@DateFrom90  = CAST(GETDATE() - 90 AS DATE)
      ,@DateFrom180 = CAST(GETDATE() - 180 AS DATE)



DECLARE @Inspectors TABLE (
        InspectorID int,
        InspectorGrade int,
        DateFrom date,
        DateTo date 
        );

insert into @inspectors  (
        InspectorID ,
        InspectorGrade,
        DateFrom ,
        DateTo 
        )

select tmp.InspectorID  , tmp.InspectorGrade 
      ,case when tmp.VisitWithReport = 0 then @DateFrom180 else @DateFrom90 end StartDate
      ,@DateTo EndDate
from
(
    select i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade 
          ,VisitWithReport = (select COUNT(v.visitid) 
                              from visits v
                              inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
                              where v.ReportStandard not in (0,9) and v.VisitType = 1
                              and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom90 and @DateTo
                              and s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID)    
    from inspectors i
) tmp;


SELECT i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade 
      ,TotalVisitsWithAtLeastOneReport = (select COUNT(distinct v.visitID) 
                                          from Visits v 
                                          inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
                                          inner join VisitDocs vd on vd.VisitID = v.VisitID 
                                          where vd.DocType IN (1,2,13) and s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID
                                          and v.VisitDate BETWEEN i.DateFrom and i.DateTo

                                          )
from @Inspectors  i
```

[image]

Comment: not good query, all I can say. you have better options.

Comment: The reason this is slow is because you are using a cursor.

Comment: those subselects on `COUNT(v.visitid)` and `COUNT(distinct v.visitID)` are what's probably killing the speed, to be sure you should include (pictures of) the execution plan taken for that whole script

Comment: I have already tried cursor but same taking too much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767996/select-query-in-cursor-taking-too-long

Comment: @SeanLange where is the cursor?

Comment: In the first Count() you want to count also when v.visitid is null or you want to count only when is not null?, can you tell me the number of records you are inserting on inspectors?

Comment: Never try a cursor to improve speed. What you have right now with correlated subqueries is essentially a cursor on each one as they operate record by record. Get rid of the correlated subqueries and replace with derived tables or joins.

Comment: @MelgoV: if there is no visit then it should be 0

Comment: So you can replace COUNT(v.visitid)  with COUNT(1) and also try changing @Inspectors for a #temp table, not always is better tables variables.

Comment: @Blam the original post talked about a cursor. The OP said there was a cursor...silly me...I assumed they used a cursor since they said so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked my sql in query tunning advisor and after creating following non cluster indexes, sql script is now taking only two to three seconds to execute. I will test this more and will see if it is not going to effect other part of the system before implementing in live.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [DocType_VisitID] ON [dbo].[VisitDocs] 
(
[DocType] ASC,
[VisitID] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON  [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it down and see where it is not performing

```
select i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade 
          ,VisitWithReport = (select COUNT(v.visitid) 
                              from visits v
                              inner join InspectionScope s 
                              on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
                              where v.ReportStandard not in (0,9) and v.VisitType = 1
                              and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom90 and @DateTo
                              and s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID)
from inspectors i
```

Try this - you give the query optimizer a lot more chances to get smart

```
select i.InspectorID, i.InspectorGrade
     , COUNT(v.visitid) as VisitWithReport
  from inspectors i
  join InspectionScope s 
    on s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID        
  join visits v
    on v.ScopeID = s.ScopeID     
   and v.ReportStandard not in (0,9) 
   and v.VisitType = 1
   and v.VisitDate BETWEEN @DateFrom90 and @DateTo
 group by i.InspectorID, i.InspectorGrade


SELECT i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade 
      ,TotalVisitsWithAtLeastOneReport = (select COUNT(distinct v.visitID) 
                                          from Visits v 
                                          inner join InspectionScope s on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
                                          inner join VisitDocs vd on vd.VisitID = v.VisitID 
                                          where vd.DocType IN (1,2,13) and s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID
                                          and v.VisitDate BETWEEN i.DateFrom and i.DateTo

                                          )
from @Inspectors  i
```

try

```
   SELECT i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade
        , COUNT(distinct v.visitID) as TotalVisitsWithAtLeastOneReport
     from @Inspectors i
     join InspectionScope s
       on s.InspectorID = i.InspectorID
     join Visits v
       on s.ScopeID = v.ScopeID 
     join VisitDocs vd 
       on vd.VisitID = v.VisitID 
      and vd.DocType IN (1,2,13) 
      and v.VisitDate BETWEEN i.DateFrom and i.DateTo
    group by i.InspectorID , i.InspectorGrade
```

Comment: query in TotalVisitsWithAtLeastOneReport is causing problem

Comment: @user1263981 How would I know?   Did you vote me down?

Comment: and you should declare a PK on @Inspectors TABLE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61549/discussion-between-user1263981-and-blam).

Comment: @user1263981 I don't know how to use chat.  If you have a question then post it.  I did not vote your question down.